# Is there a name for the set $\{T,F\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, boolean-algebra

Is there a name for the set containing the two Boolean values, i.e. $\{T,F\}$?

I am also thinking if $B = \{T,F\}$, and $B^n = \underbrace{B \times B\times B ... \times B}_n$, then is there a proper name for $B^n$? I thought of something like "Boolean n-space", but Google shows me that's not how people refer to it. I really appreciate it it someone can point me to the relevant terms and concepts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know that $\{ T \}$ is called the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth.  As for $B^n$, wouldn't "Boolean lattice with $n$ atoms" work?  That also captures the partial order on your set.

Comment: Oh gosh. All of you are very helpful and I've no idea which should be choosen as the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Two-element Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra)**, at least according to Wikipedia.

Comment: B gets called the Boolean domain.  "The set of truth values" will also work as a label.

Comment: @Doug: There are *more* truth values if you consider mutli-valued logic.

Comment: You speak correctly.  If the context of classical logic (not its formulas however) comes as clear, in other words if you've presupposed {T, F} as the domain of truth and you haven't stated it, you could say "the set of truth values".  "Classical truth set" perhaps might work better.

Answer (score 1):

It's more common in mathematics to represent "truth values" as 0 and 1.  The set $\{0,1\}$ is sometimes denoted just as $2$, especially by set theorists.  The $n$-fold product would then be $2^n$.  This notation looks confusing at first, but is usually unambiguous in context.  (It also matches up with the usual construction of integers as finite ordinals, where $0 = \emptyset$, $1 = \{\emptyset\}$, and $2 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} = \{0,1\}$.)